# Match records with a combination of regex and lookup

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data-wrangling, fuzzy-comparison

I want to match personal records between two tables using the following logic:

1. Regex match on last name up to minor variations - summarized by the following regex for a given last name: `grepl("LNAME( .r|-| [ivx]|.*)", last_name, ignore.case = TRUE)`.
   The function `fuzzyjoin::regex_*_join` was suggested, but I'm not sure how to use it if the name isn't static...?
2. Match on first name based on the nicknames list. So basically matching all names in `nicknames[[fname]]` or just `fname` if that is empty. Should not be case-sensitive as well.
3. Exact match on city, not case-sensitive.

Right now I'm just iterating through df1 and implementing this logic by hand, but my data set is large and it's taking way too long, plus the manual implementation doesn't lend itself to parallelization, which is a concern as I willwant to optimize this in the future. There has to be a smarter way of doing this.

Example data:

```
df1 <- tibble("lname1"=c("SMITH","BLACK","MILLER"),
              "fname1"=c("JOHN","THOMAS","JAMES"),
              "city"=c("NEW YORK","LOS ANGELES","SEATTLE"),
              "id1"=c("aaaa","bbbb","cccc"),
              "misc1"=c("bla","ble","bla"))

df2 <- tibble("lname2"=c("Smith Jr.","Black III","Miller-Muller","Smith"),
              "fname2"=c("Jon","Tom","Jamie","John"),
              "city"=c("New York","Los Angeles","Seattle","New York"),
              "id2"=c("1111","2222","3333","4444"),
              "misc2"=c("bonk","bzdonk","boom","bam"))

nicknames <- list("john"=c("john","jon","johnny"), 
                  "thomas"=c("thomas","tom","tommy"),
                  "james"=c("james","jamie","jim"))
```

Expected output:

```
expected_output <- tibble("id1"=c("aaaa","aaaa","bbbb","cccc"),
                          "id2"=c("1111","4444","2222","3333"),
                          "lname1"=c("SMITH","SMITH","BLACK","MILLER"),
                          "fname1"=c("JOHN","JOHN","THOMAS","JAMES"),
                          "lname2"=c("Smith Jr.","Smith","Black III","Miller-Muller"),
                          "fname2"=c("Jon","John","Tom","Jamie"),
                          "city"=c("New York","New York","Los Angeles","Seattle"),
                          "misc1"=c("bla","bla","ble","bla"),
                          "misc2"=c("bonk","bam","bzdonk","boom"))

# A tibble: 4 x 9
  id1   id2   lname1      fname1 lname2        fname2 city        misc1 misc2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>  <chr>         <chr>  <chr>       <chr> <chr> 
1 aaaa  1111  SMITH       JOHN   Smith Jr.     Jon    New York    bla   bonk  
2 aaaa  4444  SMITH       JOHN   Smith         John   New York    bla   bam   
3 bbbb  2222  BLACK       THOMAS Black III     Tom    Los Angeles ble   bzdonk
4 cccc  3333  MILLER      JAMES  Miller-Muller Jamie  Seattle     bla   boom
```

EDIT:

This is as far as I got. Spent the past few hours trying to get the last step done but I can't. I have this:

```
df <- tibble("fname1"=c("JOHN","JOHN","JOHN"),
             "lname1"=c("SMITH","SMITH","SMITH"),
             "fname2"=c("FRANK","JOHN","BILL"),
             "lname2"=c("SMITH","SMITH","SMITH"),
             "city"=c("NEW YORK","NEW YORK","NEW YORK"))

nicknames_df <- tibble(fname = names(nicknames), nick = paste0("^(", sapply(nicknames, paste, collapse = "|"), ")$"))

>df
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  fname1 lname1 fname2 lname2 city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 JOHN   SMITH  FRANK  SMITH  NEW YORK
2 JOHN   SMITH  JOHN   SMITH  NEW YORK
3 JOHN   SMITH  BILL   SMITH  NEW YORK

>nicknames_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  fname  nick                
  <chr>  <chr>               
1 john   ^(john|jon|johnny)$ 
2 thomas ^(thomas|tom|tommy)$
3 james  ^(james|jamie|jim)$
```

Expected output:

```
> out
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  fname1 lname1 fname2 lname2 city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 JOHN   SMITH  JOHN   SMITH  NEW YORK
```

How do I join it with nicknames df to get just the 2nd row?!

`out <- df %>% fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(nicknames_df, ???)`

Answer (score 1):

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(
  df2, df1, by = c(lname2 = "lname1"),
  ignore_case = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 4 x 10
#   lname2        fname2 city.x      id2   misc2  lname1 fname1 city.y      id1   misc1
#   <chr>         <chr>  <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <chr> <chr>
# 1 Smith Jr.     Jon    New York    1111  bonk   SMITH  JOHN   NEW YORK    aaaa  bla  
# 2 Smith         John   New York    4444  bam    SMITH  JOHN   NEW YORK    aaaa  bla  
# 3 Black III     Tom    Los Angeles 2222  bzdonk BLACK  THOMAS LOS ANGELES bbbb  ble  
# 4 Miller-Muller Jamie  Seattle     3333  boom   MILLER JAMES  SEATTLE     cccc  bla
```

I didn't want to assume any resolution for `city.x` vs `city.y`; while it's clear visually that they're good, I'll let you work through that.

Comment: This works for the example but I would like to include the desired regex explicitly somehow - is that possible?

Also, what about the first name match?

Comment: The pattern is explicitly in the second frame's (`df1` above) join fields. If you want (for example) `^`/`$`, then put them on the string. To use your `nicknames`, I think you may benefit from making it a frame with `nicknames_df <- data.frame(fname = names(nicknames), nick = paste0("^(", sapply(nicknames, paste, collapse = "|"), ")$"))` and then fuzzy-joining that in as well. I didn't know where that was going for certain.

Comment: So you're saying first replace the last names in `df1` with the mentioned regex: `^lname( .r|-| [ivx]|.*)`

Comment: Yes. If you read `?fuzzyjoin::regex_jeft_join`, the example is `regex_left_join(diamonds, d, ...)`. Look at how `d`'s fields look, where its `regex_name` is the joining-column with the patterns to match on.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. One more thing, how do I prevent the output from duplicating `city.x`, `city.y`. The condition I need is just `city="city"` in the `by` clause

Comment: `fuzzyjoin` is very intentional about this: unlike most others (`merge(.., suffixes=)` and similar), it has no option to rename or prevent these duplicate columns. This is the author's intentional decision, not casual unfinished business. Once you join, perhaps `mutate(city = coalesce(city.x, city.y)) %>% select(-city.x, -city.y)` (which silently dismisses `city.y` if `city.x` is valid).

Comment: Having trouble with the first names still. `(...) %>% fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(nicknames_df, by = c(fname2 = "nick"), ignore_case = TRUE)` works on the small example but fails on the actual dataset. Can't figure out why that might be..

Comment: Edited the post with the final question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241682/discussion-between-spine-feast-and-r2evans).